# Не поднимается redis server в контейнере

Tags: docker, redis

Выполняю следующую команду:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 6379:6379  redis:5.0.6 redis-cli
```

Получаю такое сообщение:

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
>       not connected>

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ведь в когда вы запускаете контейнер таким образом, он не выполняет entrypoint и как следствие не запускает процесс redis внутри себя.

Попробуйте запустить сам redis обычным запуском без указания команды. И уже после этого вторым контейнером запустить вашу команду, только в аргументе cli явно указать ip хостовой(где вы запустили контейнер с redis'ом) машины

Comment: Да, действительно